# how can i see the console in a release apk?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic, what I want is to export a apk release and to see the console to detect the problems.

I know that with ionic cordova run --device I can see the console, but with that command I see a debug apk and I need to see the console when it is a release apk.

So someone knows how I can see the console when the apk was exported as a release.

Comment: use  --consolelogs parameter. -c

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that. The objective of having a release build is that all the debug flags are turned off, so it's "impossible" to debug the app (which is normal, it would be a huge security breach).